# g++ link library x.so.2 without absolute path

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, shared-libraries

This is an old qustion, but i still can not find the solution.

i have library:
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqca.so.2` (it is installed by package libqca2, and packager did not provide libqca.so link, nor I want to do that because i am looking for answer on all similar situations, not for qca example only)

so how can i include it **without providing lib full-path-name**:

- `g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lqca` will not work because of .2 extension
- `g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lqca.so.2` is not allowed
- `g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu qca.so.2` not working too.

so seems as simple question, what is the answer.

"NO IT CAN NOT" can be the correct answer if someone with gcc/g++ knowledge can say it 100% and describe something about it... but isn't it strange that gcc has both infomations (paths to look for, and correct lib name) and can not just combine it (like it does with -l param for libs with standard naming).

Comment: You *have* tried e.g. `g++ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqca.so.2`? Why don't you want to use it if it works?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because i want my Makefile work everywhere (and first -L part I already have from qt build chain) and somewhere it will be /usr/lib64... or maybe i have 10 libraries to include why not have just ONE -L... so there is 100 reasons.

Comment: It's really not possible to make a plain `Makefile` that will work *everywhere*. I recommend you find some platform independent configuration-system (like e.g. CMake) to generate the makefiles for each host.

Comment: It's not a "random" advice. It's an advice to help you go on, to continue with your portable project and not having to worry about such details. Especially since the only way to solve it using plain makefiles is to have a lot of them, at least one for each platform you target (and by "platform" I also include different Linux distributions, or even different versions of the same distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the ANSWER my self,

it is about COLON character,

`-l:libqca.so.2`

answer found here on [linux manuals](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld): -l namespec ... If namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for a file called libnamespec.a

simple and cool

Comment: Just a nitpicking. Your question is actually about linker (binutils) and not compiler (gcc/g++).

Comment: @Anton it is about linker AND compiler, because gcc use the same parameter and sends it to the linker. Usually ld is not called directly. so it is about gcc/g++ params for linking.